# How to stop creation of new File when call save in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filer

I am using Django Model like :

```
pickle_embedding_file=models.FileField(upload_to='pickle_embedding/',blank=True,null=True)
```

Whenever I call below function:

```
    def set_pickle_embeddingFile(self,dict):
    content = pickle.dumps(dict)
    fid = ContentFile(content)
    self.pickle_embedding_file.save(str(self.user_id)+"pickle.pickle",fid)
    fid.close()
```

It is creating a new file :

```
68b335fa-6838-4c11-bd2a-32526d9b112dpickle.pickle
68b335fa-6838-4c11-bd2a-32526d9b112dpickle_jHIn3B6.pickle
68b335fa-6838-4c11-bd2a-32526d9b112dpickle_KJ5zBG0.pickle
68b335fa-6838-4c11-bd2a-32526d9b112dpickle_PUepizZ.pickle
68b335fa-6838-4c11-bd2a-32526d9b112dpickle_TREbCvy.pickle
```

I want to override files or want to delete old file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete previous file prior to creating new one

```
self.pickle_embedding_file.delete()
self.pickle_embedding_file.save(str(self.user_id)+"pickle.pickle",fid)
```